# How to make str_replace work in printf?

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the underscore character in printf. But it might be missing something because it does not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
printf("%s",str_replace($fieldinfo,"_"," ")->name);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Hope this will work.](https://eval.in/760550)

**Wrong:**
`str_replace($fieldinfo,"_"," ")->name`
Here you can not treat a string or array as an object.

**Note:** `str_replace` returns either `string` or `array` but not `object`;

`printf("%s",str_replace("-","_","some-value"));` //some_value

`echo printf("%s",str_replace("-","_","some-value"));` //some_value10 //10 is length of string

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help,

considering $fieldinfo has this value "sample_value_to_output"

```
$fieldinfo = "sample_value_to_output";

printf("%s",str_replace("_"," ",$fieldinfo));
```

this will output

```
sample value to output
```

Answer (score -1):

your str_replace code is wrong

```
str_replace($fieldinfo,"_"," ")
```

it should be

```
str_replace("_"," ",$fieldinfo->name)
```